# Bar Code does not Print in crystal report

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I'm rendering a report programatically to PDF. One of the text boxes is supposed to display barcode font and it is actually not displaying anything. How can I fix this? I am using `IDAutomationHC39M` for converting string into barcode type.

Any other solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried rendering in print preview? Are you generating and viewing on the same computer? I've seen issues before where not having the font installed has resulted in a default font being used instead of the bar code, but in your case there is nothing. Perhaps nothing is shown when the PDF references some font the displaying computer doesn't have installed? Once I know more, I may write an answer.

Comment: I've seen this a lot and it is most assuredly because you don't have the proper font installed...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works for me. I went with a jQuery based bmp generator (Image generator).  It's very easy to implement and it works very well.

You can download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-barcode/downloads/detail?name=jquery.barcode.0.3.js&can=2&q=)

Just includes in your header like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js">
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.barcode.0.3.js">
</script>
```

And `div`s which need barcodes should have the same class name for example say `barcodecls".

```
<span class="barcodecls">405479</span>

<span class="barcodecls">405339</span>

<span class="barcodecls">405341</span>
```

Then run this script on document ready:

```
<script> 
       $('.barcodecls').barcode({code:'code39'}); 
</script>
```

- Here is a Demo [Link](http://jquery-barcode.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery-barcode/demo/demo.html)

Comment: How do you make it work inside a Crystal Report (.rpt) file though? I have pointed to image URLs before, but its not clear how your answer applies to a Crystal Report.